# Space leak / Bug in interaction of Control.Lens.Plated and Bound

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, haskell-lens

Using the latest version of `Bound` and `Control.Lens.Plated`, the following `transform` call causes the programm to loop infinitely and happily munches away at my RAM. Terminating the program funnily causes the correct result to be printed, although I don't know why.

I have traced the problem to the `Scope` data type. Removing it causes the program to behave as expected.

Profiling with `./program +RTS -p -h` shows `Data.Data.Lens.insertHitMap.populate` to be the problematic part. Some of the profiling is attached.

Is this expected behaviour with an official workaround or is this maybe a bug?

I am using GHC version 8.0.2, all packages with exception of `bound-2` are part of stack `lts-8.17`. The program is compiled as `ghc test.hs`. Enabling or disabling optimizations doesn't affect the problem.

As I suspect that this is a bug, I opened an [issue](https://github.com/ekmett/bound/issues/64) for this on `ekmett`'s `bound` repository (for crossreferencing purposes).

---

```
-- file: test.hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveFoldable, DeriveTraversable, 
             DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell    #-}

module Main (main) where
import           Bound
import           Control.Lens hiding (List)
import           Control.Lens.Plated
import           Data.Deriving (deriveShow1, deriveEq1)
import           Data.Data
import           Data.Data.Lens (uniplate)

data Expr a   = Var   a
              | List  [Expr a]
              | Apply (Expr a) (Expr a)
              | Lam   (Scope () Expr a)
              | Nop
              deriving (Functor, Foldable, Traversable, Data)

main = do
         print ex
         print $ transform removeTest ex

ex :: Expr String
ex = List [Apply (Var "test") $ List [Var "arg1", Var "arg2"]
          ,Apply (Var "two") (Var "three")]

removeTest :: Expr String -> Expr String
removeTest = \expr -> case expr of
                        Apply (Var "test") _ -> Nop
                        _ -> expr

instance Data a => Plated (Expr a) where
  plate = uniplate

makeLenses  ''Expr
makeBound   ''Expr
deriveEq1   ''Expr
deriveShow1 ''Expr
deriving instance Show a => Show (Expr a)
deriving instance Eq   a => Eq   (Expr a)
```

Output:

```
List [Apply (Var "test") (List [Var "arg1",Var "arg2"])
     ,Apply (Var "two") (Var "three")]
^CList [Nop,Apply (Var "two") (Var "three")]
```

---

```
 -- profiterole stats
 TOT   INH   IND
99.9  99.9    .1  MAIN MAIN (0)


99.9  99.9    .1  MAIN MAIN (0)
99.9  99.9  34.0    Main CAF (0)
65.9  65.9     -      Data.Data.Lens fromOracle (35)
65.9  65.9     -        Data.Data.Lens hitTest (0)
65.9  65.9     -          Data.Data.Lens hitTest.\ (35)
65.9  65.9     -            Data.Data.Lens readCacheFollower (30)
65.9  65.9     -              Data.Data.Lens readCacheFollower.\ (30)
65.9  65.9     -                Data.Data.Lens insertHitMap (1)
65.9  65.9     -                  Data.Data.Lens insertHitMap.populate (1)
65.9  65.9  56.4                    Data.Data.Lens insertHitMap.populate.f (1824891)
 2.3   2.3   2.3                      Data.HashMap.Base clone16 (2682671)
 2.1   2.1   2.1                      Data.HashMap.Base hash (6204631)
 1.7   1.7    .4                      Data.HashMap.Array copy (1620382)
 1.3   1.3   1.3                        Data.HashMap.Array copy.\ (1620382)
 1.1   1.1   1.1                      Data.Data.Lens insertHitMap.populate.fs (2189870)
  .9    .9    .9                      Bound.Var gfoldl (364976)
  .5    .5    .5                      Data.HashMap.Array new_ (810191)
  .5    .5    .5                      Bound.Var gunfold (364976)
  .3    .3    .3                      Data.HashMap.Base sparseIndex (3620621)
  .2    .2    .2                      Bound.Scope gfoldl (182489)
```

---

Heap profile:

[image: heap profile]

Comment: As I noted on the ticket, the problem is definitely not in `Bound`.

Comment: The problem is definitely in `lens`. I'll comment further on the ticket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just gonna answer this with: it's a bug, dfeuer [reported it](https://github.com/ekmett/lens/issues/742) to [`ekmett/lens`](https://github.com/ekmett/lens).

In the meantime using `tinplate` instead of `uniplate` is a feasible workaround.

Comment: To tag onto this with more information revealed in the ticket: sending ^C "fixes" this infinite loop because `uniplate` works by evaluating bottom, which throws an exception, which is then caught. (Crazy, but neat.) However `lens` is catching too broadly, and while the interrupt signal shouldn't count as one of those exceptions caught it unfortunately does.